# How to parse Spring configure XML into Java class

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

Basically I thought I could get the Spring XML xsd file, 
then get the bean class by xjc, and use jaxb to parse Spring XML.

But when I did below cmd got error:

```
C:\Users\lz46054.NAM\Software\jaxb-ri-2.3.0\jaxb-ri\bin>**xjc -d C:\Users\lz46054.
NAM\Software\jaxb-ri-2.3.0\jaxb-ri\bin -p com.spring.bean spring-beans-2.0.xsd**
*parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "Ref" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve thi
s conflict.
  line 554 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 583 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve t
his conflict.
  line 556 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 590 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] Property "Ref" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve thi
s conflict.
  line 922 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 940 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve t
his conflict.
  line 924 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 947 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spri
ng-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] Property "Key" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve thi
s conflict.
  line 1019 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spr
ing-beans-2.0.xsd
[ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error
  line 1022 of file:/C:/Users/lz46054.NAM/Software/jaxb-ri-2.3.0/jaxb-ri/bin/spr
ing-beans-2.0.xsd
Failed to parse a schema.*
```

How to fix above issue? And did Spring already provide the API to read the configure file?(without loading the real class)

Comment: To understand the issue better, Are you trying to configure spring using XML configuration and load that XML file yourself?

Comment: Why would you need all that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I am trying to read our project spring xml and do some static analysis

Comment: read our project spring xml and do some static analysis